# Maps between rooted trees using forest (and TiKz)

Tags: trees, forest

I had to draw rooted (upward oriented) trees (with leaves). I found the package *forest* useful, although most likely the work-arounds I employed are not really optimal in any proper sense. An example of such a tree may be the following.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}
%opening
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=north, circle, draw, minimum width=0.7cm,anchor=center,fit=rectangle,
    edge={>=stealth,-,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,line width=0.5pt},
    scale=0.75,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}
    %
 [, node options'
  [$l$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{a}}
    [$l'$, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{b}}
      [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{e}}]
      [, node options', no edge
    ]
      [, node options', edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{f}}]
    ]
    [, node options', no edge
    ]
    [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{c}}
    ]
    [, node options', no edge
    ]
    [$l''$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{d}}
    ]
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Question.** How can I draw an arrow from one rooted tree to another one, as it is done (using xypic) at page 7 of this paper [1]?

[1] http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701293v2.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option, allowing perhaps finer control over the arrows in case [**cfr**'s solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217714/3954) is not directly usable, would be to place the trees in TikZ's `\node`s and then to use the nodes' names to draw the arrows.

The safer way to do this would be to first box the trees and then use the boxes inside a `tikzpicture`; in the following example I used the same tree three times, but this same idea can be applied for different trees using a different box for each one of the trees.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox\boxa% we define a new box

% we fill the box
\savebox\boxa{%
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=north, circle, draw, minimum width=0.7cm,anchor=center,fit=rectangle,
    edge={>=stealth,-,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,line width=0.5pt},
    scale=0.75,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}
    %
 [, node options'
  [$l$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{a}}
    [$l'$, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{b}}
      [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{e}}]
      [, node options', no edge
    ]
      [, node options', edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{f}}]
    ]
    [, node options', no edge
    ]
    [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{c}}
    ]
    [, node options', no edge
    ]
    [$l''$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{d}}
    ]
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm and 0.5cm]
\node[inner sep=0pt] (uc)
  {\usebox\boxa};
\node[inner sep=0pt,below left=of uc] (ll)
  {\usebox\boxa};
\node[inner sep=0pt,below right=of uc] (lr)
  {\usebox\boxa};
\begin{scope}[shorten >=10pt,shorten <=10pt]
\draw[->]
  (ll.north) -- node[auto] {$\partial_{v}$} (uc);  
\draw[->]
  (lr.north) -- node[swap,auto] {$\partial_{w}$} (uc);  
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Is there a straightforward way of imposing a consistent style on edge labels? (Other than rewriting the edge path, which can have unwanted side effects.) I'm not sure whether this is a generic TiKZ question.

Comment: Amazing! I was hoping for something like that. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One way is to draw the trees as a single tree with a phantom root node:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% just for this example as my editor uses this encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=north, circle, draw, minimum width=0.7cm,anchor=center,fit=rectangle,
    edge={>=stealth,-,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt,line width=0.5pt},
    scale=0.75,font=\sffamily\small\bfseries}
    %
[,phantom, l sep=0pt, s sep+=20pt
  [, node options'
    [$l$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{a}}
      [$l'$, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{b}}
        [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{e}}]
        [, node options', no edge
      ]
        [, node options', edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{f}}]
      ]
      [, node options', no edge
      ]
      [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{c}}
      ]
      [, node options', no edge
      ]
      [$l''$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{d}}, name=node1
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [, node options'
    [$l$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{a}}
      [$l'$, edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{b}}, name=node2
        [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{e}}]
        [, node options', no edge
      ]
        [, node options', edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{f}}]
      ]
      [, node options', no edge
      ]
      [, node options', edge label={node[midway,left,font=\scriptsize]{c}}
      ]
      [, node options', no edge
      ]
      [$l''$, edge label={node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{d}}
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
  \draw [->, >=stealth, shorten >=10pt, shorten <=10pt, thick] (node1.east) -- (node2.west);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: phantom root]